# App cancels with fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location

I'm designing `myCurrentLocationBtn` and got an error at `let center` when I switching off geolocation

```
@IBAction func CurrentLocation(sender: AnyObject) {

        let Authflag = CLAuthorizationStatus.self

        print(Authflag)

        let userLocation = locationmanager.location

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

        var currentAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        currentAnnotation.coordinate = center
        currentAnnotation.title = "You're here!"

        MapApple.addAnnotation(currentAnnotation)


}
```

The error is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

How can I fix it?

With disabled geolocation such function

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        locationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print (error)
   }
```

error this `Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use guard to make sure it's not nil:

```
@IBAction func CurrentLocation(sender: AnyObject) {

    let Authflag = CLAuthorizationStatus.self

    print(Authflag)

    guard let userLocation = locationmanager.location else {
     //tell the user that an error occurred
     return
    }

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    var currentAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    currentAnnotation.coordinate = center
    currentAnnotation.title = "You're here!"

    MapApple.addAnnotation(currentAnnotation)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location) `location` property has this note:

> The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.

So the problem is that when location services are disabled, your CLLocationManager doesn't have any location, and he returns nil. And when you are trying to create CLLocationCoordinate2D for center, you are force-unwrapping nil value:

```
userLocation!.coordinate.latitude
```

One of the possible solutions to this is to check that you actually get any location:

```
if let userLocation = locationmanager.location {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

and instead of creating `MKPointAnnotation` do nothing, or show some UI that will notify user that he need to enable location services in order to see his position on the map.

Also take look at `+[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled):

> You should check the return value of this method before starting location updates to determine whether the user has location services enabled for the current device. Location services prompts users the first time they attempt to use location-related information in an app but does not prompt for subsequent attempts. If the user denies the use of location services and you attempt to start location updates anyway, the location manager reports an error to its delegate.